# Problem displaying label and checkbox in column header using <apex:facet>

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I am trying to display a text label and check box side by side as a column header in an `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. Below is my code where I am trying to achieve this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accList">
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="acc">
              <apex:column value="{!acc.name}">
                  <apex:facet name="header">{!$Label.Name}<apex:inputCheckbox /></apex:facet>
              </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:form>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But on the header only check box is displayed and not the label. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the wrong format for the label merge field, hence nothing is being displayed. If you used `<apex:outputLabel value="{!$Label.Name}"/>` you'd see the error. The value you're trying to display is for custom labels that are defined at an org level.

You can fix this by using `{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}`.

That said, if you are trying to use a custom label, or the account name field's label, *both cases require* that you use an `<apex:outputPanel>` tag inside the facet to group the components together like so:

```
<apex:facet name="header">
  <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}"/><apex:inputCheckbox />
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:facet>
```